# How to join several arrays in one?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, datetime-format

I have this array:

```
[{"temp":"24.44","time":"2021-11-26 22:23:29.370657"},
 {"temp":"25.44","time":"2021-11-26 22:23:35.411530"}]
```

And I need this:

```
data.addRows([
    [24.44, [22, 23, 29]], 
    [25.44, [22, 23, 35]]
  ]);
```

It is to be able to make a graph.

Comment: You want to extract the `.temp` parameter and the `hour`, `minute`, `second` of the `.time` parameter? as `[temp, [hour, minute, second]]` ? Did you create the array in the code where you're wanting this result? Might help to include other code you've written for this.

Comment: Can you post the code which you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** You can make use of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to achieve the desired result.

```js
const arr = [
  { temp: "24.44", time: "2021-11-26 22:23:29.370657" },
  { temp: "25.44", time: "2021-11-26 22:23:35.411530" },
];

const result = arr.map((o) => [
  +o.temp,
  o.time.split(" ")[1].split(".")[0].split(":").map(Number),
]);

console.log(result);
```

**2)** You can also use regex here `[^\s]+([^\.]+)/`:

[image]

```js
const arr = [
  { temp: "24.44", time: "2021-11-26 22:23:29.370657" },
  { temp: "25.44", time: "2021-11-26 22:23:35.411530" },
];

const result = arr.map(({ temp, time }) => {
  const [a, b, c] = time.match(/[^\s]+([^\.]+)/)[1].split(":");
  return [+temp, [+a, +b, +c]];
});

console.log(result);
```